# Using BeautifulSoup to extract table

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I would like to extract the table from the following URL: "https://www.nordpoolgroup.com/en/Market-data1/#/nordic/table", and eventually store it in a pandas dataframe.

The code bellow returns:

table day-headers="true" enable-filter="false" nps-data-table="" table-data="ctrl.data[ctrl.selectedTab].table.data"></table

```
URL = "https://www.nordpoolgroup.com/en/Market-data1/#/nordic/table"
page = requests.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')

print(soup.find('table')[0])
```

I am not sure how to continue. I have been able to extract the content under the table tag on other sites using this code. Could someone please give me some advice and maybe explain what is happening in this case?

Comment: parse that URL https://www.nordpoolgroup.com/api/marketdata/page/11?

Comment: How would I do it using BeautifulSoup?

Comment: if you want to parse table then you will have to use `for`-loop to search rows `<tr>` and nested `for`-loop to search cells `<td>` in every row.

Comment: if table uses standard `<table>`, `<tr>`, `<td>` then you can use directly `many_df = pd.read_html(URL)` and laster use index to get some table -i.e. `df = many_df[0]`

Comment: I checked this page - it uses JavaScript to create table but `requests` and `BeautifulSoup` can't run JavaScript - and it would need to use [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) to control real web browser which can run JavaScript. It will be faster to use url from @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη comment.

Comment: Thanks! How do you get the url: https://www.nordpoolgroup.com/api/marketdata/page/11 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from pprint import pp
import requests


def main(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    pp(r.json())


main('https://www.nordpoolgroup.com/api/marketdata/page/11')
```

from here you can parse it as JSON and create your dataframe!

Comment: Thanks! Maybe a stupid question. But where do I find the URL: "https://www.nordpoolgroup.com/api/marketdata/page/11"